# phpexcel read 18 digitals long number from cell

Tags: php, phpexcel

I use phpexcel read and import a CSV file one of which cells is a 18 digits long, like 123456789123456789, though I use `ini_set("precision", "18");` but the value I get is not correct. How to solve this problem?

```
    ini_set("precision", "20");
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('CSV')
                    ->setDelimiter(',')
                    ->setInputEncoding('GBK')
                    ->setEnclosure('"')
                    ->setLineEnding("\r\n")
                    ->setSheetIndex(0);
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($file);

    $worksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

    foreach ($worksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
        echo 'Row number: ' . $row->getRowIndex() . "\r\n<br>";

        $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
        $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(false); // Loop all cells, even if it is not set
        foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
            if (!is_null($cell)) {
                echo 'Cell: ' . $cell->getCoordinate() . ' - ' . (string)$cell->getValue() . "\r\n<br>";

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In comments you mentioned that the wrong output has two additional zeroes. This is surely caused by a wrong interpretation of a decimal separator, so that it is treated as a thousands separator.

Change your PHP server's regional settings so it uses the point as the decimal separator -- you might need to change your thousands separator as well (if it currently is a point).

Comment: My PHP Server is  64-bit.The problem is  when the cell number is 123456789123456789, `$cell-getValue();` returns  123456789123456700,the last two number is not correct.

Comment: Change your regional settings. This sounds like a decimal separator issue: on one side it is a dot, on the other a comma, and so the number gets interpreted wrong.

Comment: I change `setDelimiter(',')` to `setDelimiter('.')`.  Bingoooooooo,Your solution is quite right. It's a lovely answer.Thanks trincot.

Answer (score 0):

```
Convert the long integer to string you can read the value
$value = 123456789123456789;
$value = (string)$value;
```

Comment: The result is the same. `$cell->getValue();`  I am afraid of what this returns is not correct.

Comment: try this ''$cell->getValue()''

Comment: For `echo 'Cell: ' . $cell->getCoordinate() . ' - ' . "$cell->getValue()" . "\r\n<br>";`  I get `()`. For `echo 'Cell: ' . $cell->getCoordinate() . ' - "' . $cell->getValue() . "\"\r\n<br>";` the result is not correct.

Comment: what is in $cell->getValue() ?

Comment: You need read phpexcel source code and find how does it work. I can not answer your question because I don't know.

Comment: hi dude 
    $keyCell = $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1,5)->getFormattedValue();//

Answer (score 0):

Last Try

```
$keyCell = $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1,5)->getFormattedValue();
```

now replace the $cell->getvalue() into $keyCell
    and
Here 1,5 is static column and row, In your code you have to use it dynamically